# Drag and drop from LaTeXit to PowerPoint

Tags: latexit

I am using LaTeXiT 2.8.0, MacTeX 2015 and PowerPoint 15.18 on OS X 10.11.  Dragging and dropping from LaTeXiT to PowerPoint does not work.  The equation simply doesn't appear in PowerPoint (there's no error message).

However, copying and pasting (right click, Copy the image as ...) does work between the two applications.

I tried the "PDF", "PDF with outlined fonts" and "PNG" export formats in LaTeXiT.  None of them worked with drag and drop.

Dragging to Keynote works, but I need PowerPoint (not Keynote or Beamer, etc.)  Dragging to Word 15.18 also works.

Why is this happening?  Is it specific to my machine or is it broken for everyone?  Is LaTeXiT just incompatible with PowerPoint 2016?  **Most importantly, is there a fix?**

Comment: Just a confirmation that this is not unique to my computer would be useful.

Comment: Not a real solution, but after suffering from this problem, too, I got used to using CMD+OPTION+SHIFT+C to copy the pdf and then CMD+V to paste into powerpoint.

Comment: Both directions of drag-and-drop work perfectly fine with my PowerPoint 2019 v16.32 + LaTeXiT v2.14.4 + macOS 10.15.2.

Comment: @modnar Good to know that it works with recent versions! Nowadays I tend to use PowerPoint's (much improved since then) equation editor.

Comment: @Szabolcs I have been using IguanaTeX for Mac for a while. https://github.com/ray851107/IguanaTexMac

Answer (score 3):

Using the same version of LaTeXit and Powerpoint 15.19.1, I got drag and drop to work  <del>by right-clicking in the output display field on the top half of the LaTeXit window and choosing 'PNG' from the 'Copy the image as' list.  I could **not** get the drag-and-drop to work by left-click dragging from the output display field and then choosing the 'PNG' button from the pop-up toolbar.</del>

After generating your output in LaTeXit, left-click and drag a small distance to make the pop-up toolbar appear, and while still holding the left mouse button, hover over the 'TIFF' option and release. You should see the 'TIFF' button blink briefly. You can now drag and drop the (raster image) output into Powerpoint 15.19.1. Note that right-clicking in the output display field and selecting 'TIFF' does not work.

Comment: Do you mean drag and drop or copy and paste?  Copy and paste works for me, but I cannot get drag and drop working with PowerPoint 15.20.  Can you tell me what you did exactly?

Comment: My fault @Szabolcs, I didn't correctly reproduce the steps I used to get the drag-and-drop to work.  I found the following to be reproducible, and have edited my original answer.  After generating your output in LaTeXit, left-click and drag a small distance to make the pop-up toolbar appear, and while still holding the left mouse button, hover over the 'TIFF' option and release.  You should see the 'TIFF' button blink briefly.  You can now drag and drop the (raster image) output into Powerpoint 15.19.1.  Note that right-clicking in the output display field and selecting 'TIFF' does not work.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. But note that this is the same as as changing the export format to `tiff` in Preferences, which is a more permanent (and simpler) solution. At least, that works for me.

Answer (score 2):

The drag and drop from LaTeXiT to Powerpoint works with the tiff format set in Preferences.  What does not work for me is the reverse process.  With Powerpoint 2011 I could drag and drop a formula from PowerPoint into Latex, and modify it as needed.  I don't seem to have that option anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed PDF files into a PowerPoint 2016 for Mac presentation. However, you can insert a link to the PDF file into your presentation so that you can open and view it during your slide show.

Source: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Can-you-insert-PDF-files-into-a-PowerPoint-2016-for-Mac-presentation-7e6ed15f-7955-4e21-a8a5-3ffa260606c4

Comment: That's a weird and confusing support article. One-page PDF figures can generally be included in PowerPoint presentations on Mac.  I don't know if it stores the PDF file itself or whether it converts it to something, but the fact is that it works.  Actually it must work as PDF is what OS X uses as a clipboard format for such graphics (I think ...)  It definitely used to work with older PowerPoint and older LaTeXit ...  There's also the fact that copy/paste works, only drag/drop fails.

Comment: I think the article may be referring to embedding multi-page PDFs and opening them in a separate viewer, or something like that ...